# Angular - Creating a new module dynamically, and injecting it into main app's dependencies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm hoping to do some lazy loading in my angular app -- I want to pull down everything I need to render the landing page, and then subsequently pull down the rest.

The problem is, it seems like I have to define all of my angular module dependencies up-front, when I first run the app...

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// then, after 1st page render:

var myModule = angular.module('myApp.subModule', []);
```

How do I now inject `myApp.subModule` into the dependencies of `myApp`?

Thanks!
-Daniel

Answer (score 4):

You can use ocLazyLoad for this purpose.
https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

The way I understand - you include ocLazyLoad.js in your code.
Then, instead of `angular.module('app',['module1','module2'])` your code becomes `angular.module('app',['oc.lazyLoad'])`.

Then you inject $ocLazyLoad into your controller and use it like `$ocLazyLoad.load({name:'module1', files:['js/controllers/module1.js']},{name:'module2',files:['js/controllers/module2']})`.

You can check out the examples on the github page.